# My cloud page is not pre-populating values in form used on page

Tags: form

I am landing to a cloud form and trying to pre-populate the form used on the cloud form.
Below are the different scripts I have used to resolve this, unfortunately it didn't work

Script 1:
I have appended "HCP_Email_Address" in my cloud page URL which is coming to browser. I have used smart capture form on page.

```
  %%[
  var @id, @HCPName, @HCPEmail, @SalesEmail
 SET @id = queryParameter('HCP_Email_Address')
 SET @HCPName = Lookup('Shashi_Kant_MasterTable_POC-4','HCP_Name','HCP_Email_Address',@id)
 SET @HCPEmail = Lookup('Shashi_Kant_MasterTable_POC-4','HCP_Email_Address','HCP_Email_Address',@id)
SET @SalesEmail = Lookup('Shashi_Kant_MasterTable_POC-4','Sales_Rep_Email','HCP_Email_Address',@id)
]%%
```

Script 2:
In this case I have used this method to populate values

```
 %%=CloudPagesURL(PageID)=%%

 %%[
var @HCPEmail
set @HCPEmail = Lookup("Shashi_Kant_MasterTable_POC-4", "HCP_Email_Address", "HCP_Email_Address", _subscriberKey)
]%%
```

Please help me on this to resolve.

Comment: Of note, I don't think your efforts in obscuring personal info on that screenshot are string enough - someone might be able to figure out the info in it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.